# Can't create user through WSO2 IS in Active Directory as secondary store?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have configured read/write AD as secondary store in WSO2IS 5.3.0. I can see the AD users in List users but can not create an AD user through management console. Updated my AD relevant properties:

```
<Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://10.100.1.102:389</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=admin,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
      <Property encrypted="true" name="ConnectionPassword">kuv2MubUUveMyv6GeHrXr9il59ajJIqUI4eoYHcgGKf/BBFOWn96NTjJQI+wYbWjKW6r79S7L7ZzgYeWx7DlGbff5X3pBN2Gh9yV0BHP1E93QtFqR7uTWi141Tr7V7ZwScwNqJbiNoV+vyLbsqKJE7T3nP8Ih9Y6omygbcLcHzg=</Property>
      <Property name="UserSearchBase">OU=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameAttribute">cn</Property>
      <Property name="UserDNPattern">cn={0},OU=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
      <Property name="GroupSearchBase">OU=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=com</Property>
```

I get following error when I create an AD user from WSO2 IS management console:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090CD7, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v2580 ]; remaining name 'cn=testuser'.

[2017-12-14 16:29:10,142] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} -  Error while enabling the user account. Please check password policy at DC for user : testuser
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your AD side password policies and check whether the provided password for the test user is complying that.

[1] https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731699(v=ws.11).aspx